# Push items in array asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, q

I want to push an object into array that one of the field is value need to get from async function

```
function loadContentAsync(url) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    request(url, function (err, res, html) {
        if (!err) {
            deffered.resolve(html);
        }
    });
    return deffered.promise;
}

var aList = $('#mCSB_5_container ul').find('a');
console.log(c);

var list = [];
aList.each(function (i, elem) {
    var html = loadContentAsync(this.attribs.href);
    list.push({
        title: $(this).text(),
        url: this.attribs.href,
        content: html
    });
});
```

But when I run this code, because `loadContentAsync` function doesn't return value synchronously, the html field will be null.

How can I this field asynchronously?

Comment: Does loadContentAsync function returns anything normally?

Comment: Most async operations take succes and failure callbacks. Manipulate the async data inside the callback. Or use promises.

Comment: Yea loadcontentasync should either return a promise or accept a callback that gets the data. Unfortunately, if you do it wrong, you'll store the data in wrong order

Comment: I've edited my question. my `loadContentAsync` return promise.

Comment: That's not a correct way to return or resolve a promise I'd say...

Comment: @deceze so, what it the correct way?

Comment: What kind of promise library are you intending to use? Deferred? Had a look at the examples? https://github.com/medikoo/deferred/blob/master/examples/while-loop.js

Comment: @MiladKhajavi: for one thing, your `loadContentAsync` function never initialises `deferred`. See [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) on how to fix it.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit You still forgot to call `deferred.reject` when appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the promises to be resolved. In order to maintain the correct order of the elements, you should use `Q.all()` to accumulate the results of all the promises:

```
function loadContentAsync(url) {
    var defer = Q.defer();
    request(url, function (err, res, html) {
        if (err) {
            defer.reject(err);
        }
        else {
            defer.resolve(html);
        }
    });
    return defer.promise;
}

var aList = $('#mCSB_5_container ul').find('a');
console.log(c);

var promises = aList.map(function (i, elem) {
    return loadContentAsync(this.attribs.href);
}).get();

var list = [];
Q.all(promises).then(function (htmlList) {
    htmlList.forEach(function (html) {
        list.push({
            title: $(this).text(),
            url: this.attribs.href,
            content: html
        });
    });
});
```